# SVN post commit hook: record number of pages in LaTeX document?

Tags: svn, latex, post-commit

I would like to record how the number of pages of my LaTeX document grows over time.

I store the `foo.tex` file in my SVN repository, so I'm thinking I can use a `post-commit` script for that, which runs LaTeX automatically (whenever changes to `foo.tex` are committed), extracts the number of pages and writes it into the log file.

Is that the right approach? Any tips / suggestions on how to best implement it? For example, how do I set it up so that the script is only called when changes to `foo.tex` are committed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows

```
@echo off
SET SVNLOOK=C:\Program Files\CollabNet Subversion Server\svnlook.exe
SET GREP=D:\SVN\Repo\hooks\grep.exe

("%svnlook%" changed -t %2 %1 | "%grep%" "^U.*/foo.tex") && (shell out to make the modification)
```

I'm not sure what command you would use to actually set the revprop...  I'm still researching...

I think that during the transaction, the message is read-only.
You may have to delay-execute

```
svn propset --revprop -r ## svn:log "MESSAGE"
```

if the prop needs updating.